# C++ Linking Error and Undefined Reference in Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

So I have looked all over for an answer to this and just can not seem to find one that isn't specific to a specialized library. I'm currently learning c++ by way of Stroustrup's Principles and Practice and, while I normally use visual studio on my PC, wanted to test things out with Xcode on my mac. For some reason, the following code comes up with the two errors copied at the bottom of this post.

```
#include "libc++.h" // just a header file with the std library info copied from stroustrup's website

using namespace std;

string error(){

    string s;
    throw runtime_error(s);

}

class Token{
public:
    char kind;
    double value;

};

class Token_stream{

public:
    Token_stream();
    Token get();
    void putback(Token t);

private:
    bool full {false};
    Token buffer;
};

void Token_stream::putback(Token t){
    if(full) error("Full putback()");
    buffer = t;
    full = true;
}

Token Token_stream::get(){

    if(full){
        full = false;
        return buffer;
    }
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    switch(ch){
        case ';':
        case 'q':
        case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
            return Token{ch};
        case '.':
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case'5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {   cin.putback(ch);
            double val;
            cin >> val;
            return Token{'8', val};
        }
        default:
            error("Bad Token");
    }
    return Token{0};
}

double expression();
Token_stream ts;

double primary(){

    Token t = ts.get();
    while(true){
        switch (t.kind) {
            case '(':{
                double d = expression();
                t = ts.get();
                if(t.kind != ')') error("Expected ')'");
                return d;
            }
            case 8:
                return t.value;
            default:
                error("Primary value expected");
        }
    }


}

double term(){

    double left = primary();
    Token t = ts.get();
    while(true){
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':
                left *= primary();
                t = ts.get();
                break;
        case '/':{
            double d = primary();
                if(d == 0) error("Bad input: Can not divide by zero.");
                left /= primary();
                t = ts.get();
                }
        default:
                ts.putback(t);
                return left;

        }

    }

}

double expression(){

    double left = term();
    Token t = ts.get();
    while(true){
        switch(t.kind){
            case '+':
                left += term();
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            case '-':
                left -= term();
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            default:
                ts.putback(t);
                return left;
        }
    }
}




int main()
try {

    while(cin)

        cout << '=' << expression() << '\n';

}
catch(exception& e){

    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n';

}
```

I know it's not documented super well, but it's just me going through the exercises in the book. I end up with these two errors whenever I try to build.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "Token_stream::Token_stream()", referenced from:
>        ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see >invocation)

I figure that it wants me to link some library in the build phase, but I don't know what extra library I would need. Also, my makeshift libc++ is just because I have no idea how #include the standard library in xcode so if you are feeling extra helpful any advice on that would also be great. Thank you!

Comment: `Token_stream();` -- So where is this function?  That's what the linker is complaining about.

Comment: So the book is wrong? Can you tell me what page this is on?

Comment: @sebenalern I'm on a PDF so pages are screwed up. It's section 6.8 and the code is `class Token_stream {
public:           Token_stream();           Token get();           void putback(Token t);
 
private:

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah I figured out that it was just an issue with redundancy and the definition of Token_stream referencing itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wow I feel like such an idiot for not realizing this but right after posting I read through the code and realized it was a redundancy while defining the Token_stream class. For anyone reading this with the same issue, Stroustrup's example includes Token_stream() within the Token Token_stream{} and it's wrong.